# How to compile julia with multiple modules?

Tags: compilation, package, julia, static-compilation

I'm trying to compile and get an executable of a julia module. This module is in `file.jl` and it uses 2 more modules in 2 different files. I tried to use [`juliac.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl#static-julia-compiler) but it didn't work.

I tried the package compiler on this script in julia:

```julia
using PackageCompiler

build_executable(
"recocido_simulado.jl",#This is the file where is my main
snoopfile = "base_datos.jl", #This is an extra file which I use in the main
builddir = "/" 
)
```

Comment: Interesting topic/question.  Could you make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  And -> "... it didn't work ..."  What didn't work?  Was there an error message?  Was an executable created?

Comment: It just didn't compile, I run the example hello.jl that have a println and throw up lots of errors.